# Aligned, hanging indents in non-monospaced code

Tags: math-mode, indentation, code

I want to typeset a piece of code containing line breaks.  New lines should indent to a specified point in the previous line.  Here is a monospaced example to illustrate what I mean.  Notice how 'case' and 'of' line up below, as well as 'let' and 'in':

```
swap : forall a, b. Tuple a b -> Tuple b a
swap a b x = case x
             of tuple a b y z. let x' = tuple b a z y
                               in x'
```

The code I want to typeset is not monospaced, so I can't just use a verbatim environment to get what I want.  The actual LaTeX of the first line, for instance, is

```
\mathsf{swap} : \forall\alpha,\beta.\;\mathsf{Tuple}\;\alpha\;\beta\to\mathsf{Tuple}\;\beta\;\alpha
```

How can I align some text to a specific point in the previous line?

Comment: Could you use a `tabular`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tabbing` one can set dynamically the tab stops:

```
\begin{tabbing}
$\mathsf{swap} : \forall\alpha,\beta.\;\mathsf{Tuple}\;\alpha\;\beta\to\mathsf{Tuple}\;\beta\;\alpha$\\
$\mathsf{swap}\;\alpha\;\beta\;x={}$%
  \=$\mathsf{case}\;x$\\
  \>$\mathsf{of}\;\mathsf{Tuple}\;\alpha\;\beta\;x\;z.\;$%
    \=$\mathsf{let}\;x'=\mathsf{Tuple}\;\beta\;\alpha\;z\;y$\\
  \>\>$\mathsf{in}\;x'$
\end{tabbing}
```

With `\=` one sets a tab stop valid from that line onwards, with `\>` we go to the next tab stop.

[image]

It's also possible to cancel tab stops previously set by using again `\=`.

Answer (score 5):

There are various ways to accomplish this:

1. You can use `\phantom{<arg>}` to leave as much space as taken up by `<arg>`.  So in this case you would do:

   `\phantom{swap a b x = }of tuple a b y z. let x' = tuple b a z y`

   `\phantom{swap a b x = of tuple a b y z. }in x'`

   `\phantom{}` will take up as much horizontal *and* vertical space as its parameter. There is also a `\vphantom{}` which takes up as much vertical space as its parameter but zero horizontal space, and a corresponding `\hphantom{}` that takes up as much horizontal space as its parameter but zero vertical space.
2. As @egreg commented, you can also use the `tabbing` environment as shown below.
3. As @cmhughes commented you could also use `tabular`.

---

Each of these yield similar results:

[image]

### Notes:

- Although the tab spaces are hard coded below, they could easily be computed using `\widthof{}` available with [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc). Or better still, see solution provided by egreg which shows how to use `tabbing` properly.
- Since a MWE was not provided, I guessed at the definitions.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Case}{\mathsf{case}}%
\newcommand{\Let}{\mathsf{let}}%
\newcommand{\Swap}{\mathsf{swap}}%
\newcommand{\Tuple}{\mathsf{Tuple}}%
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\Swap : \forall\alpha,\beta.\;\Tuple\;\alpha\;\beta\to\Tuple\;\beta\;\alpha$

\noindent
$\Swap : \alpha,\beta x = \Case\; x$

\noindent
$\phantom{\Swap : \alpha,\beta x ={}}of \;\Tuple\; \alpha \beta y z. \;\Let\; x' = \Tuple\; \beta \alpha z y$

\noindent
$\phantom{\Swap : \alpha,\beta x = of \;\Tuple\; \alpha \beta y z.}\in x'$

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{0em}\=\hspace{6.5em}\=\hspace{6.8em}\=\kill
%
\>$\Swap : \forall\alpha,\beta.\;\Tuple\;\alpha\;\beta\to\Tuple\;\beta\;\alpha$\\

\>$\Swap : \alpha,\beta x ={}$\>$\Case\; x$\\

\>\>$of \;\Tuple\; \alpha \beta y z. \;\Let\; x' = \Tuple\; \beta \alpha z y$\\

\>\>\>$\in x'$
\end{tabbing}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l@{}l@{}l@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{$\Swap : \forall\alpha,\beta.\;\Tuple\;\alpha\;\beta\to\Tuple\;\beta\;\alpha$}\\
$\Swap : \alpha,\beta x ={}$&$\Case\; x$\\
&$of \;\Tuple\; \alpha \beta y z. \;$&$\Let\; x' = \Tuple\; \beta \alpha z y$\\
&&$\in x'$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabbing}...\end{tabbing}`?

Comment: @egreg: Well, ummm..... yes that would be simpler, but then how would I be known for providing the overkill solution? :-)  I never use that environment so it never occurs to me.

Comment: Neither do I use it. :) I can delete my comment to cover your tracks. :)

Comment: @egreg: Sure. Might as well... I use `\phantom` so often, perhaps that means I am doing things wrong (well at least not in the most efficient way).

Comment: Your solution with `tabbing` could be much improved. :)

Comment: @egreg: Yep, that is why I had added in the **Notes** to see your solution for a better version of `tabbing`. Perhaps it would be better for me to just remove the `tabbing` portion of this answer?  Let me know what you think.

Comment: The one with `\phantom` is quite good, actually. It requires copying the same row a few times, but it's then easy to add `\phantom` and the braces at the appropriate spots. The `\noindent` can be avoided using ``\\*`` (no page breaks) or a `minipage`.

Comment: `tabbing` was the easiest for me, but I'll keep the phantom technique in mind.